# Picking values twice with multithread [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, multiprocessing

I'm trying to apply some multithreading to my codes, therefore I was trying to practice with some easy tasks.
In the following simple code I want every thread to take one value of a counter (m), then increase its value, and then make somthing using the value previously taken and copy the result of it in a list (listL)..
Unfortunately I can't prevent the thread to take the same value twice...
It's probably trivial but I can't find a proper solution...
Thanks in advance..

Mario

```
imports System.Threading

Module Module1
    Public m As UShort = 0
    Dim listL As New List(Of Integer)

Sub Main()
    Dim t1 As New Thread(AddressOf TestMultiThreading)
    Dim t2 As New Thread(AddressOf TestMultiThreading)

    t1.Start("a")
    t2.Start("b")

    t1.Join()
    t2.Join()

    For m As Integer = 0 To listL.Count - 1
        For n As Integer = m + 1 To listL.Count - 1
            If listL(n) = listL(m) Then Debug.Print("same {0} {1}", n, m)
        Next n
    Next m

    listL.Clear()

End Sub

Public Sub TestMultiThreading(ByVal X As Char)
    Dim lobj1 As New Object
    Dim p As Integer

    Do While m < 100
        SyncLock lobj1
            p = m
            m += 1
        End SyncLock
        ' various calculations ...
        ' eventually
        listL.Add(m)
    Loop

    lobj1 = Nothing

    Debug.WriteLine("end " & X)

End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this test.  Take a look at the differences, especially how the lock object is outside the loop, and the value p is added to the list, not m.

```
Module Module1
Public m As Integer = 0
Dim listL As New List(Of String)

Sub Main()
    Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf TestMultiThreading)
    Dim t2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf TestMultiThreading)

    t1.Start("a")
    t2.Start("b")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(0)
    t1.Join()
    t2.Join()

    For xm As Integer = 0 To listL.Count - 1
        Debug.WriteLine(listL(xm))
        For n As Integer = xm + 1 To listL.Count - 1
            If listL(n) = listL(xm) Then
                Debug.Print("same {0} {1}", n, xm)
            End If
        Next n
    Next xm

    listL.Clear()
    Stop
End Sub

Dim lobj1 As New Object

Public Sub TestMultiThreading(ByVal X As Object)

    Dim p As Integer
    Dim c As String = DirectCast(X, String)
    Do While m < 100
        SyncLock lobj1
            p = m
            m += 1
        End SyncLock
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(0) ' various calculations ...
        ' eventually
        'listL.Add(p.ToString & c) 'for debug
        listL.Add(p.ToString)
    Loop


    Debug.WriteLine("end " & c)

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your time, I've to say that I miss the meaning of the lock Obj declared outside the sub...or maybe..is it to make it "global"? In that case in my poor code the lock was not locking anything I guess :P, but I'm not grasping the *.thread.sleep(0) use...

Comment: The sleeps were there to make sure both threads were running since I don't have the actual code.  The lock was local so each thread had its own, moving it outside meant each thread was using the same lock.